# AWS S3.getSignedUrl() : semantics of expiry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a large dataset stored in an AWS S3 bucket. The access to the S3 bucket is non-public and I am using API gateway to perform authorization before the S3 bucket can be accessed. Authorized users are returned a signed url using S3.getSignedUrl() API call which they could use to fetch the large object.

My question is regarding the semantics of the expiry duration passed in the parameter object to the getSignedUrl call.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
```

My understanding is that the URL expires after the Expires duration (60 seconds in this example).

The question is: Can I use a short expiry URL that returns a large object for which the GET request itself might take much longer (say 15 minutes)?

> **[S3 SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property):**
>
> params (map) — parameters to pass to the operation. See the given
> operation for the expected operation parameters. In addition, you can
> also pass the "Expires" parameter to inform S3 how long the URL should
> ***work for*** (emphasis added).

I want to avoid having to provide longer expiration duration than necessary from a security point of view. I am trying to understand the meaning of '*how long the URL should work for*' in the documentation.

Intuitively, I feel the getSignedUrl() returns a signed URL that is valid for 60 secs (in this example) and if a GET request is triggered within the expiry of the signed URL, AWS will authorize the request and fulfill the request even if it takes 15 mins to stream the object back to the requestor. This should work as long as the GET request to the underlying object is issued prior to expiry. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption, that your large object can be downloaded in a **single** GET request that is correct, authorization happens when you issue that request.

If you need multiple GET requests with the range-header, each of these is authorized separately.

I tried it:

```sh
$ URL=$(aws s3 presign s3://mb-demo-bucket-2020/130MB.txt --expires-in=10)
$ wget -q $URL                                                            
Time: 0h:00m:23s
```

The download takes 23 seconds and the URL was only valid for 10 seconds.